# Sending logs of (rootless) podman containers to ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, redhat, filebeat, podman

I am struggling with the $question for a while and it is time to ask for some guidance.
We have 10+ containers that runs on different RHEL VMs deployed via ansible as systemd service (in other words, there is no cubernetes or other container orchestration service on top of /next to podman installed)
These containers are running as rootless containers. Unfortunately the docker (podman) socket is not active on the VMs (albeit we can turn it on).
All the VMs has filebeat installation.
We have an ELK stack separately deployed.
What I have found during working on this:

- the podman (installation here) supports only k8s-file and journald logging (problem #1: the easiest way would be to use json-file logging driver combined with docker/podman socket, this could not be achieved here)
- the podman socket belongs to the podman user who runs those rootless containers so it is not really visible for the others, even the root could not see the running containers without the podman socket – I was able to work this around (so the root was able to list the running containers), but I don’t think so / could not believe that this should be the industrial standard solution
- switching to journald and using the journalbeat: this may work, but I don’t know that this can be combined with container metadata collecting that would be required to be able to distinguish the VM logs from the container logs

I am looking for a solution for this setup that would make the centralized logging working in the asiest way.
For now I would be grateful for some hints about a working concept.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In addition, on all VM one user runs all the containers - no need to search for containers runned by other user(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [journald input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-input-journald.html) in Filebeat so you don't need to deploy Journaldbeat (deprecated) separately.

journald natively supports structured data in logs (you can run `journalctl -o json` to see what fields are in your logs). So if the journald log driver is passing container metadata through to journald then the events produced by Filebeat will contain fields like `container.{id,name,image.tag}` (assuming it follows the same field naming as the [Docker journald log driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/)). Or if it uses a custom naming convention then Filebeat will produce events with fields like `journald.custom.*`.

Here's what the podman logs look like on my machine when running `journalctl -o json | jq -S .`

```
{
  "CODE_FILE": "src/ctr_logging.c",
  "CODE_FUNC": "write_journald",
  "CODE_LINE": "264",
  "CONTAINER_ID": "ee059a097566",
  "CONTAINER_ID_FULL": "ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac",
  "CONTAINER_NAME": "modest_heyrovsky",
  "CONTAINER_PARTIAL_MESSAGE": "true",
  "MESSAGE": "10.0.2.100 - - [29/Aug/2023:16:46:50 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 45",
  "PRIORITY": "6",
  "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "conmon",
  "_AUDIT_LOGINUID": "1000",
  "_AUDIT_SESSION": "4",
  "_BOOT_ID": "f5f4c28d95df4cfaaac4d7ec5e33eeb5",
  "_CAP_EFFECTIVE": "1ffffffffff",
  "_CMDLINE": "/usr/bin/conmon --api-version 1 -c ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac -u ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac -r /usr/bin/crun -b /home/ubuntu/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac/userdata -p /run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac/userdata/pidfile -n modest_heyrovsky --exit-dir /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp/exits --full-attach -s -l journald --log-level warning --runtime-arg --log-format=json --runtime-arg --log --runtime-arg=/run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac/userdata/oci-log -t --conmon-pidfile /run/user/1000/containers/overlay-containers/ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac/userdata/conmon.pid --exit-command /usr/bin/podman --exit-command-arg --root --exit-command-arg /home/ubuntu/.local/share/containers/storage --exit-command-arg --runroot --exit-command-arg /run/user/1000/containers --exit-command-arg --log-level --exit-command-arg warning --exit-command-arg --cgroup-manager --exit-command-arg systemd --exit-command-arg --tmpdir --exit-command-arg /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp --exit-command-arg --runtime --exit-command-arg crun --exit-command-arg --storage-driver --exit-command-arg overlay --exit-command-arg --events-backend --exit-command-arg journald --exit-command-arg container --exit-command-arg cleanup --exit-command-arg ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac",
  "_COMM": "conmon",
  "_EXE": "/usr/bin/conmon",
  "_GID": "1000",
  "_HOSTNAME": "linux",
  "_MACHINE_ID": "0829fb9723294fceb0eddbf4c45b197b",
  "_PID": "6088",
  "_SELINUX_CONTEXT": "unconfined\n",
  "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1693327610600063",
  "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": "/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/user.slice/libpod-conmon-ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac.scope",
  "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID": "98a1d7a85cf048eaa726b6e5aadbb043",
  "_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID": "1000",
  "_SYSTEMD_SLICE": "user-1000.slice",
  "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "user@1000.service",
  "_SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE": "user.slice",
  "_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT": "libpod-conmon-ee059a097566fdc5ac9141bfcdfbed0c972163da891de076e0849d7b53597aac.scope",
  "_TRANSPORT": "journal",
  "_UID": "1000",
  "__CURSOR": "s=66bb92cf8741499ca3d9dd4ef84dd0a4;i=2427;b=f5f4c28d95df4cfaaac4d7ec5e33eeb5;m=18f10791ee;t=604128eb7daa0;x=41277d78955a13c3",
  "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "107123020270",
  "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1693327610600096"
}
```

Additionally when using the Filebeat journald input you might want to apply a filter to only ingest data from podman. This would produce the same data as `journalctl _COMM=conmon`.

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: journald
  id: podman-container-logs
  include_matches.match:
    - _COMM=conmon
```

Comment: I accepted your answer albeit it is not fully describe all changes I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any relevant in this topic so I decided to provide a more detailed description about how I solved this problem:

1. Yes, the answer of A.J. was one of the starting point where I begun, so I had to use filebeat with journald input, so I had to add this section to the filebeat.yml:

   ```
   filebeat.inputs:
   - type: journald
       enabled: true
       id: podman-container-logs
   ```
2. but along that, I had to modify the podman_user who runs these containers to be able to read/write the journal:

   ```
    usermod -a -G systemd-journal podman_user
   ```
3. enable the podman socket:

   ```
   systemctl --user enable podman.socket
   systemctl --user start podman.socket
   loginctl enable-linger podman_user
   ```
4. in filebeat.yml in the processors section I had to define the correct location of the podman socket:

   ```
     - add_docker_metadata:
         host: unix:///run/user/985/podman/podman.sock
   ```
5. in the same file, because I used logstash to submit the journal events to elastic and because after a while the filebeat event transfer halted, I had to add a ttl to the output.logstash section:

   ```
   output.logstash:
     hosts: ["logstash1.local:5044","logstash2.local:5044"]
     ttl: 120s
   ```
6. in /usr/share/containers/containers.conf (maybe in your system the main podman config is at different location) I updated the events logger:

   ```
   events_logger = "journald"
   ```
7. (Optional) enable the logstash logging in filebeat.yml:

   ```
   logging.level: debug
   logging.selectors: [logstash]
   ```
8. last, but not least I had to switch the log driver of my container from (the default) k8s-file to journald in my ansible scripts:

   ```
           - name: Running {{ app_name }} in podman container:
             name: "{{ app_name }}"
             image: "path/myimage:latest" 
             log_driver: "journald"
   ```

Some other useful tricks:

You can run filebeat manually after you stop the filebeat service:

```
     # stop run filebeat as linux service
     systemctl stop filebeat.service
     # you can check that your filebeat.yml configuration is still valid with this command:
     filebeat -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml test config
     # manual execution:
     filebeat -e - -d "*" -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```